# bitbucket ci cd pipelines ssh connection failed

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

> ssh -i ~/home/devops/.ssh/authorized_keys kiran@35.194.42.142
>   Warning: Identity file /root/home/devops/.ssh/authorized_keys not accessible: No such file or directory.
>   Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
>   Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

my authorized_keys is in the same location, but it will show no such file or directory

my .yml file is

```
image: node:8.14.0
```

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          #- echo "Everything is awesome!"
          #- npm install 
          #- echo "Build files"
          #- echo "$(ls -la)"
          #- npm install -g @angular/cli@1.6.4
          #- ng build -prod
          #- cd dist/ 
          #- echo "$(ls -la)"
          - echo "Connect to server"
          - ssh -i ~/home/kiran/.ssh/authorized_keys kiran@35.194.42.142
          - scp -r README.md kiran@35.194.42.142:/home/kiran/temp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple things here.

1. The file `~/home/kiran/.ssh/authorized_keys` doesn't exist in the `node:8.14.0` Docker image. (This is the main part of the error message - `No such file or directory`.)
2. `authorized_keys` is a list of *public* keys. `ssh -i` needs a private key.
3. `authorized_keys` is only used to validate *incoming* connections - if the new connection request is signed by a private key that corresponds to one of the public keys in `authorized_keys` then the connection is authorized. You cannot use `authorized_keys` to establish an outgoing connection, and Pipelines here is attempting to establish an outgoing connection.

You'll need to set up the private key in Pipelines and to add its corresponding public key to `authorized_keys` on the remote system. https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-ssh-keys-in-bitbucket-pipelines-847452940.html has some instructions there.